# Homemade Randomized RSA

Tags: rsa, randomness, padding, semantic-security

Considering the following encryption scheme where RSA is used to encrypt a plaintext **m** and then we choose a random **r** and compute: $$A = r + m^e \bmod N$$  and $$B = r^e \bmod N$$ So the ciphertext is a pair: $$(A,B)$$ and to recover **m** we compute: $$m = (B^d - A)^d \bmod N$$ IMHO This scheme has not randomized encryption since this padding approach is wrong, but i cannot figure out why. Can anyone give me a little hint?

Comment: Suppose you take a guess at $m$. Will you be able to tell if $(A,B)$ is an encryption of $m$ or not? (You will.)

Comment: I'm able to tell if (A,B) is an encryption of m but with non-negligible advantage since even if i query an oracle multiple times with the same message m, i'll obtain different encryption of the same plaintext. So or i'm wrong or this approach is not deterministic unlike textbook RSA

Comment: You don't need to query an oracle to encrypt in the public key setting, just "do the math yourself".

Comment: "Giving to an adversar A the public key pk being used to encrypt the message, effectively gives A access to an encryption oracle for free"

Comment: You can use the public key to implement an encryption oracle, but that's not the *only* thing you can do with it. So, you know $e$ (since it's public), and have a guess for $m$. What can you do with those? Will it help you answer @Henrick's question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Spartacus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/30267/spartacus): Maybe i came out with the solution, since the cryptosystem described above is not **CCA-secure**, an adversary **A** can intercept **(A,B)** and compute a new ciphertext $$C = 2B\bmod N = 2^er^e \bmod N$$ Since he's carring out a CCA-attack he has access to a decryption oracle and since: $$C\neq B$$ the oracle output $$RSA^{-1}(C) = 2^{ed}r^{ed}\bmod N = 2r\bmod N$$ So he can simply recover **r** by half of computed plaintext, and computing **r - A** he obtains the deterministic encryption of the message. Is it right?
- [Artjom-B](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/13022/artjom-b): You forgot something $2^eB\bmod N=2^er^e\bmod N$. I don't think this is complete, because the decryption oracle would decrypt $(A,C)$ and not $C$ alone.
- [Spartacus](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/30267/spartacus): Maybe it's true but by definition i can't query a decryption oracle with original challenge ciphertext A. If it were possibile we got zero chance of getting a CCA-secure cryptosystem
- [SEJPM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/23623/sejpm): Hint1: This scheme isn't even IND-CPA secure. Hint2: [What Henrick said.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/homemade-randomized-rsa#comment73516_31639) Hint 3: Given $(A,B,m,e,N)$, can you somehow recover $r$, possibly using A and m somehow?

---

Okay, let's prove that the scheme is not IND-CPA secure:

1. An adversary **A** outputs two messages $m_0,m_1$.
2. A uniform bit $b$ is chosen $b \leftarrow \{0,1\}$ and then the challenge ciphertext $C$ is computed as follows: $$ A = r + m_b^e \bmod N$$ $$B = r^e \bmod N.$$
3. The pair $(A,B)$ is output to the adversary **A**.
4. Before guessing the value of $b$ the adversary **A** still has access to the public key, so he can compute the two deterministic encryptions of $m_0$ and $m_1$ as follows: $$C_0 = m_0^e \bmod N $$ $$C_1 = m_1^e \bmod N$$.
5. Now he can compute the two possible plaintext values of **r** as follow  $$P_r^1 = A - C_0 $$ $$P_r^2 = A - C_1.$$
6. A doesn't know yet which of the two possible computed plaintext values was used, but he has the ciphertext of the right one and the public key, so he computes $$ C_r^1 = (P_r^1)^e \bmod N$$ $$ C_r^2 = (P_r^2)^e \bmod N.$$
7. Now he can simply compare the ciphertexts as follows: 
   if $C_r^1 = B$ then use $P_r^1 $, else use $P_r^2 $.
8. Let $P_r^k$ be the chosen value. Now the adversary can simply compute the deterministic encryption of the challenge ciphertext $C$: $$ C_d = A - P_r^k \bmod N.$$
9. Now it's easy guess the value of $b$: if $C_d = C_0$ then $b'=0$, else $b'=1$.

So the probability that A output $b'=b$ is equal to $1$; the encryption scheme is not IND-CPA secure.